# Inline editing function causing multiple ajax requests from single click

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here is my sample code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Rf3pU/1/

When I goto do an inline edit, and click submit - it fires 2 JSON requests to the server, and I am unsure why.

Anyone see any issues within my JavaScript?

Comment: That jsfiddle is useless. Try fixing it too first.

Comment: I am able to make the first inline edit correct, and changes are saved. The error appears to be happening upon trying to update the newly updated information inline.

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rf3pU/2/